# Teardown method does not get executed if there is error in test

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I had did automation testing using Selenide/Selenium. There is tear down method using @AfterClass but it is not executed when there is error in test.

```
@BeforeSuite
public void init() {

}

@AfterClass
public void tearDown() {
    Write to html file
    extentManager.getExtentReports().flush();
    emailManager.sendEmail();
}

@Test
public void testHome() {
    extentTest = extentManager.getExtentReports().createTest("Home Test");

    $x("//*[@id=\"__next\"]/div/div[4]/div/ul/li[1]/a").hover();
    $x("//*[@id=\"navbarNavDropdown\"]/ul/li[1]/a").click();
    $x("//*[@id=\"navbarNavDropdown\"]/ul/li[1]/a").shouldHave(Condition.exist);
    $x("//*[@id=\"__next\"]/div/div[4]/div/ul/li[1]/a").shouldHave(text("HOME"));
    $x("//*[@id=\"navbarNavDropdown\"]/ul/li[2]/div[1]/a").shouldHave(Condition.exist);
    $x("//*[@id=\"navbarNavDropdown\"]/ul/li[3]/div[1]/a").shouldHave(Condition.exist);
}
```

Anything wrong with the annotation? Should I use different annotation?

Comment: What test-framework  and versionare you using? TestNG or JUnit?

Comment: TestNG version 7.6.0

Comment: Are you sure the tearDown isn't being executed? Some unit testing frameworks do a bad job of reporting errors in the setup/teardown phases of a test. Errors can happen that are not necessarily obvious when looking at the test results. Have you tried debugging it by setting a breakpoint in your code?

Comment: Do you have only one test in your class?

Answer (score 0):

you can change your AfterClass annotation to this: `@AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)`. This will make sure that your tearDown method will always run even if previous methods failed.

Documentation can be found [here](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html)